# Wordpress Civi Installer Error

Tags: wordpress

I've a fresh install of wordpress with no other plugins activated. Hosting is https://www.blacknight.com/medius-hosting.html

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the installer.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (class 'HTMLPurifier_Bootstrap' not found)' 
in /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php:122 

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php(122): spl_autoload_register(Array, true, false) 
#1 /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php(90): CRM_Core_ClassLoader->initHtmlPurifier(false) 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/install/index.php(76): CRM_Core_ClassLoader->register() 
#3 /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(777): include('/var/www/vhosts...') 
#4 [internal function]: CiviCRM_For_WordPress->run_installer(' in /var/www/vhosts/37/253640/webspace/httpdocs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 122
```

Any idea why this error is occurring? Looked for a solution but could not find anything.

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Can you clarify what instructions you followed for installation?

Comment: Simply activated plugin and went to Settings -> CiviCRM Installer
wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install where error above shows

Comment: not clear - did you follow steps outlined eg http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5

Comment: Yes I followed installation (I've installed before with no issues). I get this error on Step 5. Enable CiviCRM plugin and run installer (wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install)